# Sort rows alphabetically

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is how I get my data from SQLite db:

```
getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ", null));
```

But I never get my items sorted out, even if I add **ASC**. Here is what I have:

[image]

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try execute this query from shell by connecting via adb?

Comment: No, I didn't. How to do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite)

Comment: i created a table, populated it with your data, and your query works perfectly! are you sure you don't have some whitespace in your "COLUMN_NAME_TITLE" field that might be throwing off the query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `LOWER` function:

```
"SELECT _id, " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY LOWER(" + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use orderby with ASC (ascending) to sort the items alphabetically.

```
          getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE +"ASC"+" COLLATE NOCASE ", null))
```